In Elizabeth Hand's novel "Waking the Moon", how does this character get resurrected from death?
Massive spoilers ahead.
In the novel Waking the Moon, the character Oliver castrates himself and is then taken to a hospital, and from there, to a mental hospital. After spending a few days in the mental hospital, he jumps out of a fifth floor window and dies, leaving behind a note saying “I'll be right back.”

However, at the end of the book, he returns, to all appearances perfectly alive. He presumably was resurrected somehow. Exactly when in the book did he get resurrected (assuming he really was dead), how did he get resurrected, and who was responsible?

Some further information, which may be relevant. In this book several goddesses, including Cybele, are conflated. You can see this by the invocation

Othiym, Anat, Innana, Kybele, Kali, Artemis, Athena, Hecate, Potnia, Othiym.
In hoc signo vinces,

and this conflated moon Goddess plays a major role in this book (being the titular Moon who is being woken). In Greek mythology, Attis is the consort of Cybele. And in this book, Attis also seems to be conflated with several other figures from Greek myth, including Adonis and Hyacinthus.

 In the ancient mystery cult dedicated to Attis, the priests castrated themselves, and it seems very likely to me that Oliver is supposed to have become a priest of Attis.

